# Домены приложений, время жизни

Tags: c#, appdomain, .net-framework

Рихтер пишет, что так как у типов в другом домене нету корней, то в CLR пошли на хитрость: прокси объекты живут ~5 минут с момента последнего обращения, после чего умирают.

Получается, что эти объекты нужно постоянно "пинать", что бы CLR их не выгружал, а если выгрузил, то создавать по новой?

Comment: Хм, судя по всему, да.

Comment: Вариант с реализацией [ISponsor](https://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/500)?

Comment: по статье получается, что прокси живут 5 минут с момента создания, независимо от частоты обращений, чтобы не заставлять GC лазить в соседний домен для проверки наличия активных ссылок. Так что пинай не пинай, остается только вариант с ISponsor, если нужен действительно "долгоиграющий" прокси-объект.

Comment: @ApInvent оформите в виде полноценного ответа?

Comment: @rdorn оформите в виде ответа, хотя бы краткого? 100 репутации сгорает :)

Comment: @rdorn есть еще LifetimeServices.RenewOnCallTime, по умолчанию 2 минуты

Answer (score 9, accepted):

5 минут — время жизни `MarshalByRefObject` по умолчанию (начальное, а не после последнего обращения). Его можно изменить установкой статического свойства `LifetimeServices.LeaseTime` в целевом домене:

```
public class MyObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    static MyObject()
    {
        TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
        LifetimeServices.LeaseTime = t;
    }
}
```

Но лучше, скорее всего, переопределить метод `InitializeLifetimeService` для конкретного объекта, который должен жить долго, чтобы он возвращал `null`:

```
[SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand,
                       Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.Infrastructure)]
public override object InitializeLifetimeService()
{
    return null;
}
```

Тогда для этого объекта не будет использоваться управление временем жизни и он умрет только с выгрузкой всего домена.

Comment: Есть еще LifetimeServices.RenewOnCallTime, по умолчанию 2 минуты.