# Умирает объект созданный при помощи EasyHook

Tags: c#, .net

Я немного не до понимаю время жизни меж-доменных объектов, они же `MarshalByRefObject`, но вот я поставил хук на `IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene`, далее происходит какое-то время работы объекта, но дальше, он умирает.

Сообщения от рендерера:

```
Server: Ping response time: 6
Server: Ping response time: 0
Hook installed
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 1
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 1
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 1
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 1
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 10
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 1
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
Server: Ping response time: 0
EndScene hook called, Device is: 45792640
ERROR: Renderer is destroyed!!!
Server: Ping response time: 0
ERROR: Renderer is destroyed!!!
Server: Ping response time: 0
```

Почему так происходит?

Код класса рендерера:

```
public class Renderer : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
{
    private readonly List<IntPtr> _vTable = new List<IntPtr>();
    private readonly OverlayManagerInterface _managerInterface;
    private readonly LocalHook _deviceResetHook;
    private readonly LocalHook _endSceneHook;

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private delegate int EndSceneDelegate(IntPtr devicePtr);

    public Renderer(OverlayManagerInterface managerInterface)
    {
        _managerInterface = managerInterface;

        using (Direct3D d3D = new Direct3D())
        {
            using (Form renderForm = new Form())
            {
                using (Device deviceGlobal = new Device(d3D, 0, DeviceType.NullReference, IntPtr.Zero,
                    CreateFlags.HardwareVertexProcessing,
                    new PresentParameters
                        {BackBufferWidth = 1, BackBufferHeight = 1, DeviceWindowHandle = renderForm.Handle}))
                {
                    _vTable.AddRange(GetVTblAddresses(deviceGlobal.NativePointer,
                        Enum.GetValues(typeof(D3D9Indexes.Direct3DDevice9FunctionOrdinals)).Length));
                }
            }
        }

        _endSceneHook = LocalHook.Create(_vTable[(int) D3D9Indexes.Direct3DDevice9FunctionOrdinals.EndScene],
            new EndSceneDelegate(EndScene), this);
        _endSceneHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new int[1]);

        _managerInterface.Ping(DateTime.Now);
        _managerInterface.OnManagerMessage("Hook installed");
    }

    public List<IOverlay> Overlays { get; } = new List<IOverlay>();

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetVTblAddresses(IntPtr pointer, int numberOfMethods)
    {
        List<IntPtr> vTblAddresses = new List<IntPtr>();
        IntPtr vTable = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(pointer);

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMethods; i++) vTblAddresses.Add(Marshal.ReadIntPtr(vTable, i * IntPtr.Size));

        return vTblAddresses.ToArray();
    }

    private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
    {
        foreach (IOverlay overlay in Overlays) overlay.Dispose();
        LocalHook.Release();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        _managerInterface.OnManagerMessage("ERROR: Renderer is destroyed!!!");
        _managerInterface.Ping(DateTime.Now);
    }

    private int EndScene(IntPtr devicePtr)
    {
        Device device = new Device(devicePtr);
        _managerInterface.Ping(DateTime.Now);
        _managerInterface.OnManagerMessage("EndScene hook called, Device is: {0}", devicePtr);
        device.EndScene();
        return Result.Ok.Code;
    }

    private int DeviceReset(IntPtr devicePtr, PresentParameters[] presentParameters)
    {
        Device device = new Device(devicePtr);
        _managerInterface.Ping(DateTime.Now);
        _managerInterface.OnManagerMessage("DeviceReset hook called, Device is: {0}", devicePtr);
        device.Reset(presentParameters);
        return Result.Ok.Code;
    }

    ~Renderer()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();

        _managerInterface.OnManagerMessage("ERROR: Renderer is destroyed!!!");
        _managerInterface.Ping(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Как сделать так, что бы объект не умер?

Comment: GC.KeepAlive()?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768158/Домены-приложений-время-жизни

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight: Такой вариант тоже не спасает. Буквально ~10-20 вызовов, и объект умер.